# android:targetSdkVersion HTTP request error

Tags: android

My app was working fine till now until I put the following line in android manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
```

Now the app is not making HTTP request as far as i can tell b'coz the app is not logging in. Is there anything that I'm missing.

When I use

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="9"/> or <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="7"/>
```

it works.

Comment: "is not working" is not really a helpful problem description. What exactly does not work *(e.g. can't install anymore, crashes at a certain point, ..)*?

Comment: Which API are you using to do the HTTP requests ? java.net or apache ?

Comment: Do you make all your network requests in a seperate thread instead of the UI thread? I suspect StrictMode may get in your way *(though I'm not sure if the targetSdk makes a difference)*. In case you don't use a seperate thread search for "StrictMode" and "NetworkOnMainThreadException". That should get you going.

Comment: How important is to specify <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>..?

Comment: I have implemented TabActivity in my app..Could this be a reason??

Comment: @alextsc we are using AsyncTask.

Comment: Can you show some logs? Are you using any external jars, android projects?

Comment: @yugidroid  ... logcat doesn't show anything, its just that the request is generated after a long long time.. and I'm not using any external jar or project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this Issue. The problem was that the async task was never entering `doInBackground()`. The prob was that I was using `webServiceTask.execute();` but now I changed it to if

```
(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
 webServiceTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,""); 
     else
webServiceTask.execute("");
```

It started working after this.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're making your HTTP calls from the UI thread, which is not recommended but will work with a targetVersion of 9, later versions enforce the requirement that HTTP requests be done from a thread other than the UI thread, so when you change the targetVersion to 14 this check now gets enforced. You'll need to update your app code to make HTTP calls from a different thread (checkout Loaders and/or AsyncTask to help with that)

Comment: Of note:  if this is the case, the LogCat output should show that it is happening.  You should be able to see the NetworkOnUiThread exceptions being thrown.

Comment: I'm using AsyncTask to make the request.

Comment: then post some code, and logcat output we're not mind readers.

Comment: @ superfell.. sorry i cannot post code.. I would have liked to post to make it easy to find..But due to some fu***** policies, I can't.

Comment: I would like to add one thing...When I don't use <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion>, the app runs fine even on 4.0